# where is php.ini on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, php

I don't mean the one in etc/php5/apache or cli these I found.

I renamed both of them to .old and loaded a php_info() and although the Loaded Configuration File says (none) I still don't know where the php.ini that is being used - trying to change the upload_max_filesize from 2M to 5M but whichever php.ini I found and changed (yes I also restarted apache2), still it says 2M

Comment: The linked question has an answer about a syntax error, but doesn't indicate where the files are actually located.

Comment: The location is in question, actually.

Comment: If the file exists on your system, you can find it with `find / -name "php.ini" 2> /dev/null`